# Does Session variables get affected with Concurrent access?

Tags: php, session, concurrency

I don't know how to phrase my problem (and that is probably why I am  not getting any solution through google) but just trying to think out loud as simple as I can.

Suppose in my php application there is a session variable named $_SESSION['x']. The application is currently using by user a,b,c etc. Each user sets that $_SESSION['x'] with different values. I want to know if the users are accessing concurrently, will there be any problem? or though the name is $_SESSION['x'] and users are accessing concurrently, different user will get different and UNIQUE $_SESSION['x']?

I hope I have make myself clear. Help with any clue will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Sessions are specific to a browser, so no matter how many concurrent users you have accessing the site, they will all recieve their own session variable values :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there will be no Problem, because the session Array is unique per user. And you are not even able to access an other users session.

Btw. don't forget "session_start()", you need it once per request to reinitialize or create the session and therefore the $_SESSION array.